# When I add this button to my page it offsets the other element that was previously centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am styling a page with flexbox. I had a nicely centered image inside a div with a background image.

```css
body {
  width: 700px
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc
}

.wrapper,
.banner {
  display: flex
}

.wrapper {
  flex-direction: column
}

.banner {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1000/600/?random");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 300px;
}

.banner img {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 140px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  align-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>

</nav>
<article class="wrapper">
  <section class="banner">
    <img id="profile-pic" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?random" />
  </section>
</article>
```

See this codepen:

https://codepen.io/efbbrown/pen/PmOpWo

---

Now I want to add an x button so the user can change the background image if they please. When I add the button div it pushes the centered image out of position.

Added element:

```
<section class="banner">
  <div class="close-button"></div>
  <img id="profile-pic" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?random"></img>
</section>
```

See this codepen for full dilemma:

https://codepen.io/efbbrown/pen/PmOpOq

How can I add this x button to the div without changing the positioning of the center image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex box will change the position and width of items based on the number of items contained inside the flex element.  This means that when you add the close button, your banner image is now centering based on the remaining space, not the full width.  You can "remove" an item from the flexbox formatting by changing it's position to `absolute`.  That element is now ignored by the flexbox, as it will position it's self.

This should do the trick:

```
.banner {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
}

.close-button {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    /* ... */
}
```

**EDIT**

Answer to questions from the comments below: Absolute positioning is not always determined by the width and height of the screen or window. It's actually determined by the closest 'positioned' parent, for example a parent marked as `position: relative`.

Using relative and absolute together is where absolute position really works well. In this example you can mark the banner class as position relative and wherever you move that div to, the close button will follow and position based on the banner div.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without position: absolute? I still want to position the button relative to its parent, in that I want to be able to change the height of the nav and whatever other sections may appear above the banner without having to change the styling of the close-button.

Comment: Absolute positioning is not always determined by the width and height of the screen or window.  It's actually determined by the closest parent marked as `position: relative`.  Using relative and absolute together is where absolute position really works well.  

You can mark the banner class as position `relative` and wherever you move that div to, the close button will follow and position based on the banner div.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how the banner class should be set up.

Comment: Yo that's it! Thanks so much!